# Destroy 2 caracters after a number

Tags: python, python-re

I need help, in a long string, I want to know the the 2 characters after a number

```
example = "gz15gr123da1az4gr1sd23f168zgre4r6z"
if in example after 1 number == "gr":
so delete "gr"
```

Comment: You are not looking for `2 characters after a number` in your example, rather you're looking for 2 characters before a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is regex:

```py
import re
example = "gz15gr123da1az4gr1sd23f168zgre4r6z"
re.sub("(\d)gr", r"\1", example)
```

##### Output

```
gz15123da1az41sd23f168zgre4r6z
```

##### Explnatation

The `re.sub` function takes three arguments: the first argument is a patter, the second one the replacement, and the last of is the string itself. `(\d)gr` selects the parts that contain a number followed by `gr`, then replaces it with the number (\d) itself(removing the `gr` part).

Comment: After a number if its "gr", I want destroy it
ZZZZ6grZZZZZZ1grZZZ7ZZZ -> ZZZZ6ZZZZZZ1ZZZ7ZZZ

Comment: @Aragor This code does the job you described.

Comment: It doesnt work its normal ?

Comment: I have printed the result in the output part. It should work! Didn't it remove the `gr` after a number?

Comment: import re
example = "cccccccc1gr1111gr"
print(example)
re.sub("(\d)gr", r"\1", example)
print(example)

Comment: the gr doesnt remove

Comment: @Aragor The first print would be the same as the `example` value. But I used the same code as you provided and it resulted in `cccccccc11111`

Comment: oh yes it works, i just forgot to put example = re.sub("(\d)gr", r"\1", example)

Comment: can i be faster and put directly "0123456789" instead of "1" ?

Comment: @Aragor What do you mean by `1`? the number `1` in the `re.sub` function refers to the first regex group defined in the pattern: `(\d)gr`. It actually indicates that "leave the number alone and just remove the `gr` and nothing else`.